# GitFlow - Extra Unstable Develop Branch

Tags: git-flow

GitFlow suggests that when the feature is done it is merged into develop then at some point develop is merged into master.

What happens when you are working on code that is not approved for the next release but you still want to test it (and other similar future features) together?

You can't merge it to develop because then your feature will be prematurely pushed to master.

What do people do in this case?

Do you create an extra branch for merging these future features into in order to facilitate your testing?
Is there a naming convention for this?

Comment: What about rebasing your branch to the current head?

Comment: I think the title should be  feature testing on develop branch. there's a related ticket on SO.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Vincent Driessen](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) (The Author of GitFlow Model), you have to merge all features to develop branch. Look at his own words:

> The key moment to branch off a new release branch from develop is when develop (almost) reflects the desired state of the new release. At least all features that are targeted for the release-to-be-built must be merged in to develop at this point in time. All features targeted at future releases may not—they must wait until after the release branch is branched off.

I have a few doubts about this matter too (English issues), but what I usually do is like what He present in this image:
[image]

Take a look at the last feature. You can see that it is only merged at the second release of the example. So, when I have an unfinished feature (to be tested maybe), I just ignore it until next realese.

Futhermore, GitFlow is only a model (a successful one). And like all models, it may not be completely suitble for your application. You can always try new ideas like Vincent Driessen (the author) wisely did.

Take a try, and share with us any improviments.